# nycflights13 + cumsum + group_by

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, cumsum

I am trying to plot a cumulative sum of dep_delay by carrier from the flights dataset in R (package nycflights13). I am able to do this on other datasets with no issues, so I am stumped. The issue I am having is that I can get a daily cumulative sum by carrier, but the cumulative sum keeps resetting each day. I am sure I am missing something obvious. Thank you, World!

```
flights2 <- flights %>%
  arrange(date)%>%
  group_by(carrier)%>%
  mutate(Tot_dep_delay = cumsum(dep_delay))#currently generates a daily cumsum by carrier
```

Comment: I thought I saw a very similar question asked about this same dataset yesterday. Have you done any searching of SO?

Comment: @EHL I believe `date` is not in `flights` from the `nycflights13` package. Are you using the original data with `year`, `month`, and `day`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @IRTFM and @Ben for engaging. I ended up finding an answer to my own challenge this morning. I was, as Ben said, using a date that I made, but that wasn't the issue.

It turns out dep_delay in the flights dataset has a number of NA values. Since cumsum does not seem to have an efficient na.rm=TRUE type command to calculate the value absent these rows, I needed to filter first. The following code seems to have worked.

```
flights2 <- flights %>%
  arrange(date)%>%
  filter(dep_delay!= 'NA')%>%
  group_by(carrier)%>%
  mutate(Tot_dep_delay = cumsum(dep_delay))
```